# ncurses-rs segfaults when using get_wch()

Tags: rust, readline, ncurses

I'm writing a shell history app that uses the [`ncurses-rs`](https://docs.rs/ncurses/5.99.0/ncurses/) crate, and I came across an issue with deleting entries from history - simply, it was undoable without native `readline` bindings. My program reads from a pipe (like: `histroy | hstr-rs`) which makes it impossible to manipulate history files by hand. Hence, I introduced another [unmaintained] crate called [`rl-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/rl-sys), made a small change to it (wrapped a single statement in an unsafe block) because it wouldn't compile. This change made the app compile, however, this also caused my program to segfault on start. I reached for `gdb` to see what's happening, and this is what I was able to find out:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
                                                    0x00007ffff7f47821 in doupdate_sp () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7f47821 in doupdate_sp () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7f37db8 in wrefresh () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7f307da in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7f49c64 in wget_wch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
#4  0x000055555561a604 in ncurses::get_wch ()
#5  0x00005555555935f6 in hstr_rs::main ()
#6  0x0000555555586c73 in std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace ()
#7  0x0000555555586c8c in std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}} ()
#8  0x0000555555631ae7 in core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once () at /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:259
#9  std::panicking::try::do_call () at library/std/src/panicking.rs:381
#10 std::panicking::try () at library/std/src/panicking.rs:345
#11 std::panic::catch_unwind () at library/std/src/panic.rs:382
#12 std::rt::lang_start_internal () at library/std/src/rt.rs:51
#13 0x0000555555595cf2 in main ()
(gdb)
```

Clearly, it segfaults on `get_wch()`. Just to make sure that's the cause of the issue, I tried using ordinary `getch()` and the segfault was gone. However, I need the wide version of the function.

I've talked to some people who advised me to ditch the ncurses-rs crate in favor of some other crate because ncurses-rs is "insanely unsafe", despite its functions not being marked unsafe. Easier said than done. Before ditching it and rewriting the app to use a safer alternative, I want to understand what's going on and try to fix the issue if possible because a rewrite would require a significant time investment that I can not afford at the moment.

I'm still inexperienced but a [Valgrind log](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dh5Jq2R8K5/) I obtained does not look good to me.

Comment: [`get_wch`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/get_wch) requires an argument. What is it? (Where does it point at? Where did you get that pointer from?)

Comment: It doesn't, according to https://docs.rs/ncurses/5.94.0/ncurses/fn.get_wch.html

Comment: The binding marks the calls `unsafe` (and provides the argument).  Use the [source](https://github.com/jeaye/ncurses-rs/blob/8089412606f7a9dda93c5cad60386697e999b6eb/src/lib.rs#L320).

Comment: There's no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provided, so no one can provide a suitable answer for this.